# Submit a form in JS using onsubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I ran into some issues when trying to execute a function upon form submit. I needed to add a min/max for the inputs.

The code without `onsubmit="runFunction()"` works as it's suppose to but when I wrap it into a form and use `onsubmit="runFunction()"` the function runs once but it resets everything after it's done.

The code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input class="numGuess" id="num0" min="0" max="9" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="numGuess" id="num1" min="0" max="9" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="numGuess" id="num2" min="0" max="9" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="numGuess" id="num3" min="0" max="9" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" value="Is it correct?" onclick="checkValues()">
</form>
```

The function checkValues():

```
function checkValues(){
  arr2 = [];
  Object.keys(mainGuess).forEach(function(num){
    var iterated = mainGuess[num];
    console.log(iterated.value);
    arr2.push(iterated.value);
  })
  compareArray();
}
```

compareArray() just checks if the input value is the same as another array.

The function works as long as I don't use a form and use `onclick` which changes the background of the inputs to red if wrong and green if correct. If I wrap it in a form the function runs, I can see it run briefly for a moment before it resets everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is going on, is that you are actually submitting the form. Since the form doesn't have an [`action`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) attributed to it, it just submits to itself and that ends up refreshing your page. You can solve this by preventing the submit from happening by using [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
<form>
    <input class="numGuess" id="num0" min="0" max="9" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="numGuess" id="num1" min="0" max="9" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="numGuess" id="num2" min="0" max="9" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="numGuess" id="num3" min="0" max="9" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" value="Is it correct?" onclick="checkValues(event)">
</form>
```

then in you Javascript

```
function checkValues(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  arr2 = [];
  Object.keys(mainGuess).forEach(function(num){
    var iterated = mainGuess[num];
    console.log(iterated.value);
    arr2.push(iterated.value);
  })
  compareArray();
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see, didn't knew preventDefault() existed :( Thanks!

Comment: @fupuchu glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The form you wrote is only `form` tag without any attributes, so when `submit()` function is fired, the default behavior is called, `target` is itself then make it do like refresh.
That make your input values is all gone.

So the function `checkValues()` should have parameter `event` from fired element.

`<input type="submit" value="Is it correct?" onclick="checkValues(event)">`

In function, first call `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default behavior and then last call `document.getElementById('formId').submit()` to fire the event by yourself.

Kind like this.

```
function checkValues(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...your code...
    document.getElementById('formId').submit();
}
```